# How to use more CPU cores on linux?

Tags: parallelization, linux

I noticed that `ParallelTable` of Mathematica doesn't work well on my linux   computer. WolframKernel uses just one cpu core.

then I find
[image]

That's weird..

I want to use more cores to speed up my codes, What can I do?

Comment: Have you checked `LaunchKernels[...]`?

Comment: "every time WolframKernel uses just one cpu core" <- Actually, *each `WolframKernel`* uses *at least* one CPU core. You should have as many `WolframKernel`s running as you have CPU cores.  Most operations within a single kernel use only one CPU core.  Some operations, such as matrix product (and on occasion: `NIntegrate`) will use many.

Comment: Can you show evidence that only one subkernel is running?  People will not be able to help unless they can reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does `wolframscript -code '$ConfiguredKernels'` output?

Comment: Also, can you show a reproducible example?  The example you show runs so fast that parallelization is pointless, and you couldn't possibly check the task monitor before it finishes. Show something that runs for at least 10 seconds.  Make the example complete, so we can try it without having to edit it in any way.

Comment: @Szabolcs Following your suggestion, I find that `wolframscript -code '$ProcessorCount' ` returns `1` , but I do have more than 1 CPU cores. I have edited my question.